# CreateJS Eventlistener enters multiple times on the same function

Tags: html, adobe, createjs

I'm making a HTML5 game using createJS in Adobe Flash Professional. The game has 5 timeline positions, the first is to load the game, the second shows the title of the game, the third shows the level and the instructions, the fourth shows the game itself and the fifth is reserved for a ending screen.

Each time a user passes a level it goes back from the fourth screen to the third screen to show the instruction for that level.

```
timeline.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

I have events for objects to drag/drop and it works fine on the first level, I remove the event listeners and the object stops moving as intended.

```
 for (i=0; i< numberofpairs;i++)
 {
        paresArray2[i].sym.removeEventListener("pressmove", item_onMouseDown);
        paresArray2[i].sym.removeEventListener("pressup", stage_onMouseUp);

 }
```

When it advances level it goes to the third screen then back to the fourth and I have this code again (now with increased numberofpairs),

```
for (i=0; i< numberofpairs;i++)
{
    paresArray2[i].sym.addEventListener("pressmove", item_onMouseDown);
    paresArray2[i].sym.addEventListener("pressup", stage_onMouseUp);
}
```

what happens is that now everytime the events are fired it enters twice on the functions and if I advance another level then its 3 times, and so on. How can I stop the events for entering multiple times in the same function?

P.S. I made a test where I had the event listeners twice in paresArray2[i] and it just enters once in the first level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by putting all the functions in the first frame with the format:

```
foo = function()
{

}
```

and calling them in the fourth frame.